# What are the possible ways to secure sensitive data in my Spring Boot app's database?

Tags: java, spring-boot, security, encryption

I have a spring boot app that has a database which stores customer sensitive data. I want to know how I can:

**1. Secure database credentials in properties file.** I have heard of libraries that encrypt the contents of the properties file. Which are the easiest ones to begin with? And are there other ways to secure it.

and more importantly

**2. Secure data within the database**, possibly encrypt table columns containing sensitive data.

Please suggest libraries that I can use and how to use them in order to achieve this.

Comment: 1- You can take a look at Jasypt : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-jasypt
2- before storing sensitive data in your table you can encrypt it by using multiple ways of encrypting data , the simple one is base64 encode/base64 decode, it that clear or you want an example ?

Comment: Can you suggest any libraries that can be used for stronger encryption in spring boot?

Comment: I think to encrypt datas you need to use java stuff , means some think like : https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Using_the_Java_Cryptographic_Extensions  or https://howtodoinjava.com/security/how-to-generate-secure-password-hash-md5-sha-pbkdf2-bcrypt-examples/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AWS, you can use the environment variables in the properties file, and then you can take those environment variables from the AWS secret manager or AWS Parameter Store.